# Python "not defined" in lottery

Tags: python, function, defined

Im learning for a book "Intr. Python 2.6.6" and
I have the this error in a example

```
line 12, in <module>
aux=num_ele
NameError: name "num_ele" is not defined
```

But I do not understand what the problem

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 *-*

import random
import os

def combinacion(num_ele, total_num, repetir=False, ordenar_resultado=True):
    elementos=[]
    if num_ele>total_num and not repetir:
        print ("No puedes sacar mas valores de los que ya tienes!")
        return

aux=num_ele

while aux>0:
    numero = int(random.uniform(1,total_num))
    if repetir:
        elementos.append(numero)
        aux=aux-1
    else:
        if elementos.count(numero)==0:
            elementos.append(numero)
            aux=aux-1

if ordenar_resultado:
    elementos.sort()
print (elementos)

def menu():
    print ("""
    Menu Principal

    Este programa genera combinaciones de juegos de azar. elige el juegos
    que mas te guste.

    1) Loteria Primitiva
    2) Euromillones
    9) Salir 
    """)

    opcion = input("")
    return opcion

def aplicacion():
    os.system(cls)
    opcion = ("")
    while opcion!=("9"):
        opcion = menu()
        if opcion ==("1"):
            print ("")
            print ("Combinacion para loteria primitiva: ")
            combinacion(6,49)
            print ("")

        if opcion == ("2"):
            print ("")
            print ("Euromillones")
            print ("Combinacion ganadora: ")
            combinacion(5,50)
            print ("Estrellas: ")
            combinacion(2,9)
            print ("")

aplicacion()
```

thank you for your time.

Comment: Find another book. 2.6 is an old version of Python and you should use something more recent.

Comment: @Kevin Its doesnt matter what python version he is using. No major changes between 2.6 and 2.7 which is still very much in use today

Comment: @letsc: I can't count the number of times an OP said they had 2.7, and said my answer didn't work, and it turned out they had 2.6 rather than 2.7 and I'd used a set or dict comprehension, `str.format` with implicit indices, or two files in a `with` statement. :)

Comment: In such cases the OP is probably foraying into the world of python. I am not a fan of throwing list comprehensions at people who still dont understand indentation, for loops etc.

Comment: @letsc: Well, `str.format` definitely _is_ worth showing even to rank novices. But for comprehensions: 2.6 has list comprehensions, just not set and dict comprehensions. So when, say, the OP who I won't link to has a list comprehension, and the reason his program is slow is obviously that he's doing a billion linear searches on that list, and I just change the `[…]` to `{…}` and explain why that works, but then it _doesn't_ work because he lied about his Python version, it's a little frustrating. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant to have `aux=num_ele` and the code onwards inside your `combination` function:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 *-*
import random
import os

def combinacion(num_ele, total_num, repetir=False, ordenar_resultado=True):
    elementos=[]
    if num_ele>total_num and not repetir:
        print ("No puedes sacar mas valores de los que ya tienes!")
        return
    aux=num_ele

    while aux>0:
      numero = int(random.uniform(1,total_num))
      if repetir:
        elementos.append(numero)
        aux=aux-1
      else:
        if elementos.count(numero)==0:
          elementos.append(numero)
          aux=aux-1
      if ordenar_resultado:
        elementos.sort()
      print (elementos)

def menu():
    print ("""
    Menu Principal

    Este programa genera combinaciones de juegos de azar. elige el juegos
    que mas te guste.

    1) Loteria Primitiva
    2) Euromillones
    9) Salir 
    """)
```

The indentation level of your `aux=num_ele` and the following code puts it outside `combination`'s scope.

Comment: I think the next several lines -- up until def menu -- should also be indented

Comment: Absolutely. Updated answer.